# NVidia driver won't install correctly

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kubuntu

I have a problem installing NVidia drivers. I try to install the recommended 470 driver. It gives me an output that i'm possibly missing firmware in i915. And when I try it through software sources it gives me pk-client-error-quark: error while installing package: subproces from package intramfs-tools script post-intallation returned errorvalue 1 (313). 
 So I downloaded firmware from enter link description here. And I unpacked the tarball. But don't know how to reinstall the i915 package. Please tell me how to install this.

It also won't fully install the Xorg driver ( same errorvalue 1 (313)).

I think I need to reinstall the i915 package in order to install the nvidia drivers correctly. But I'm not sure.

Because the driver won't install properly, NVidia X-settings doesn't work either.

Does anybody have a solution for me how to solve this.

I run
Operating System: Kubuntu 20.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.7
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.68.0
Qt Version: 5.12.8
Kernel Version: 5.11.0-41-generic
OS Type: 64-bit
Processors: 8 × Intel® Core™ i7-10510U CPU @ 1.80GHz
Memory: 15,3 GiB  
                                                                                                                                                                                    NVidia GeForce 250 MX (GP108M)/Intel Integrated GPU on HP Envy 17 ce1000 (laptop)

Comment: Please post here as well: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/c/gpu-graphics/linux/148

Comment: What driver version are you trying to install? It looks like your GPU should be using the v340 driver.

Comment: I try to install the 470 driver. This has ( recommended ) behind it.

Answer (score 0):

i have this problem nivida 740 GT 4 GB

pk-client-error-quark: E: dpkg werd onderbroken; voer handmatig 'dpkg --configure -a' uit om het probleem te verhelpen.
(281)

E: dpkg werd onderbroken; voer handmatig 'dpkg --configure -a' uit om het probleem te verhelpen.
E: _cache->open() failed, please report.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/425828)